# JMeter HTTP Request with no html included

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to do a HTTP request, but in the results tree (or any other sampler) I can't see the HTML of the website and I can't figure out how to do so.
I need that to check if the HTML in the response contains a substring (possibly with an assertion or stuff like that).

Answer (score 0):

If

1. Your request is successful
2. Server responds with some data
3. The HTTP Request Sampler is in the View Results Tree listener [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide/)
4. View Results Tree listener has been added before the HTTP Request sampler has been executed

You should see the "HTML" under Response Data -> Response Body tab of the View Results Tree listener.

Demo:

[image]

If you're trying to open a [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) with the View Results Tree Listener be informed that by default JMeter doesn't save response data in the .jtl files, you will need to amend [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) if you want to save response headers and data.